# Apache 2.4: Delays with TLS on base domain but not so much on subdomains

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4

On an Apache 2.4 server with SSL enabled, HTTP/1.1 and valid wildcard certificate (*I unfortunately cannot share the site's URL.*)

I recently get a consistent delay on new TLS connection.

The SSL configuration is the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.url.org
    ServerAlias www.url.org
    ServerAlias url.org

    SSLProxyEngine On
    # Force https
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName sub.url.org
    ServerAlias www.url.org
    ServerAlias url.org
    
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3

    SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    SSLHonorCipherOrder on
    # ...
</VirtualHost>
```

So far, I tried to look into:

- Apache logs: nothing of note
- server load: about 30G of RAM available and about 2% processor load
- Test it on Qualys SSL Labs: test either hangs at the TLS 1.0 step or ends with "unable to connect" (`A+` when trying with `www.url.org`)
- Test it on Immuniweb: tells me the site does not have certificates (`A+` with `www.url.org`)

Firefox timings for `url.org` (incognito, cache disabled):
[image: Timings for url.org]

Firefox timings for `www.url.org` (incognito, cache disabled):
[image: Timings for www.url.org]

I am guessing the base domain url has to recompute TLS because of the wildcard certificate, so I'm thinking of using a `RewriteRule` to keep `sub.url.org` but rewrite `url.org` to `www.url.org` and swapping the ServerName and ServerAlias.

Would these rules in the :443 vHost do the trick (production server, no touchy unless I'm sure)?

```
ServerName www.url.org
ServerAlias sub.url.org
ServerAlias url.org

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !sub\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

There still would be the massive initial delay, but still an improvement, right?

*Note: Can't use tools like `ab` for reasons*

---

**Edit** :

There is a `Subject alt names` field with both "*.url.org" and "url.org" in the certificate.

Comment: What is in the SAN of the certificate? The wildcard '*.url.org' doesn't match 'url.org'.

Comment: *"I am guessing the base domain url has to recompute TLS because of the wildcard certificate,"* - this sentence does not make any sense to me. Are you sure that the bare URL even points to the same IP address? *"test does not end (A+"* - what problems does SSLLabs exactly show?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich The SSLLabs test hangs on the SSL v2 step and never finishes. But yeah, I'm not versed in all that. While the wildcard certificate indeed does not match "url.org", my site is showing up with https and returns the wildcard as valid. Would the rewrite rule towards "www.url.org" solve the problem?

Comment: Update: There is a "Subject alt names" field with both "*.url.org" and "url.org" in the certificate.